# Unity: water movement effect in isometric city

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I want to give the idea that the river in my city is flowing but I am having an hard time to figure how.

Do you have any idea of what I should look into to?

[image]

Comment: This is a bit too unspecific. What exactly do you want to achieve (e.g.: a realistic water simulation, overlay some graphics over the river, something else)?

Comment: I am not sure about the difference between overlay and some graphics over the river but it would be one of those,